# Cannot remove a Opencv drawing from Window

Tags: python, opencv

**I have been searching through OpenCV Docs, but I was unable to find the answer to my problem**

*I want to remove all OpenCv prebuilt drawings from the image*

`Here is an example:`
[image]

with the following generic code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
# Draw a diagonal blue line with thickness of 5 px
img = cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)

while True:
    cv2.imshow('generic frame', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF is ord('q'):
        break
```

**I want the output to be like this following image**
[image]

`The background needs to stay the same, without the OpenCv drawings`

Comment: One way is to redraw the background, i.e. put a big black rectangle that covers the whole window, then redraw on top of it what you want to keep. But this sounds kind of like [an XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: In OpenCV, the **only** way is to redraw the background

Comment: I am using a camera, I have put a black background just for an generic example, Do you know how it is possible to redraw the background using a camera?

Comment: If you don't want that blue line, then why do you draw it in the first place?

Comment: I want the blue line, but I want it to disappear whenever I click on a key.

Comment: OK, then store a copy of the original image in a variable, so that you can revert back to it when you click a key.

Comment: Like @DanMašek say: instead of `img = cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)` do `img_copy = cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)` and show which one you choose.

Comment: @QuangHoang No, that would still draw into `img` and just make `img_copy` refer to the same array. First [`numpy.copy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) (or the equivalent `ndarray` member function) and then draw.